# Cannot start or setup MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-20.04

Since I tried to install MariaDB (but wanted to go back to MySQL), my MySQL is not starting and i cannot install it properly. I am using Ubuntu.

If I try to run mysql I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

If i try to restart I get

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And when I run systemctl statuts mysql.service I get this message:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-08-18 08:51:59 CEST; 10s ago
    Process: 82886 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 18 08:51:59 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

After running mysqld --initialize I get this error when running journalctl -xe

```
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 25639 and the job result is done.
Aug 18 09:09:08 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 18 09:09:08 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 18 09:09:08 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 25639 and the job result is failed.
Aug 18 09:09:22 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=17703 DF PROTO=2
Aug 18 09:09:57 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=36868 DF PROTO=2
Aug 18 09:10:32 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=53778 DF PROTO=2
Aug 18 09:10:44 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=b0:83:fe:9b:02:c4:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=192.168.2.38 LEN=71 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40730 DF PROTO=UDP SPT>
Aug 18 09:11:02 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 sudo[83205]: sustainvest : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/init.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/mysqld --initialize
Aug 18 09:11:02 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 sudo[83205]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by sustainvest(uid=0)
Aug 18 09:11:02 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 audit[83206]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=83206 comm="mysqld" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
Aug 18 09:11:02 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1629270662.160:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=83206 comm="mysqld" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
Aug 18 09:11:07 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=65174 DF PROTO=2
Aug 18 09:11:42 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=13961 DF PROTO=2
Aug 18 09:12:09 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 sudo[83205]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 18 09:12:14 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=b0:83:fe:9b:02:c4:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=192.168.2.38 LEN=71 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=36420 DF PROTO=UDP SPT>
Aug 18 09:12:17 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=48276 DF PROTO=2
Aug 18 09:12:52 sustainvest-OptiPlex-3020 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c0:3c:04:83:77:6c:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=65463 DF PROTO=2
```

Please help my I do not know what else to do! I tried every recommendation in Stackoverflow and the other internet regarding this errors...

Comment: Can you show the permission of `/var/run/mysqld` ??

Comment: Aparrently there is no such file or directory, might this be the problem?

Comment: you can try creating the dir and see how it goes